# Make one radio button select another radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a form with 8 radio buttons, 4 for System A and 4 for System B. The options for the radio buttons are CF, ISO, ISO-B, and NW. I want to make it so that when a customer selects a radio button for System A, the same button is selected on System B.

How do I make whatever I select in System A's radio buttons simultaneously selected in System B's radio buttons?

[What I am basing it off of](http://www.lesker.com/newweb/flanges/nipple_builder.cfm)

Comment: I don't see a question here, nor what HTML you are using or what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you *only* looking for jQuery solutions?

Comment: Any Solution will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a databinding framework like ReactJS to do this nicely, but here's a basic jQuery example that would work. Just listen to the "change" event on your first set of radio buttons, then use jQuery to select the appropriate radio button from the second set.

```js
$( function() {

  $("input[name='system-a']").on("change", function(e) {
     var newValue = e.target.value;
     $("input[name='system-b'][value='" + newValue + "']").prop("checked", true);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>System A</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="system-a" value="1">Option 1</input>
  <input type="radio" name="system-a" value="2">Option 2</input>
  <input type="radio" name="system-a" value="3">Option 3</input>
  <input type="radio" name="system-a" value="4">Option 4</input>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>System B</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="system-b" value="1">Option 1</input>
  <input type="radio" name="system-b" value="2">Option 2</input>
  <input type="radio" name="system-b" value="3">Option 3</input>
  <input type="radio" name="system-b" value="4">Option 4</input>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! There's only one problem I have a dropdown that changes when you select an option is there some way to make it keep the value.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("input[type='radio']").on("click",function(){
   var Name= this.name == "SystemA"?"SystemB":"SystemA";
   $("input[name='"+Name+"'][value='"+this.value+"']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>System A</span>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="SystemA" value="CF"/><lable>CF</lable>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="SystemA" value="ISO"/><lable>ISO</lable>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="SystemA" value="ISO-B"/><lable>ISO-B</lable>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="SystemA" value="NW"/><lable>NW</lable>
<hr>
<span>System B</span>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="SystemB" value="CF"/><lable>CF</lable>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="SystemB" value="ISO"/><lable>ISO</lable>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="SystemB" value="ISO-B"/><lable>ISO-B</lable>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="SystemB" value="NW"/><lable>NW</lable>
```